# Help using android ClipDrawable

Tags: android, eclipse, drawable

I've been trying to figure out how to cut a drawable in my resources to make another drawable.

I have a large drawable containing all of the tiles I'm going to use to create a game map on the phone. I would like it if I could use ClipDrawable to select the tile I want as opposed to manually doing it on photoshop.

(This is my first program so I'm not very good at this yet)
Here is what I could get it to do so far but I have 50 different types of tile so I think it would be easier to crop them all out of the same image.

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


     for(int i = 0; i < Tiles.length; i++){

      if(Tiles[i].isVisible()){
      /* Make the sprite draw itself to the canvas */
      if(Tiles[i].Render == 0){
          this.tile4.setBounds(Tiles[i].mySpritePos.x, Tiles[i].mySpritePos.y,
                  Tiles[i].mySpritePos.x + 26, Tiles[i].mySpritePos.y + 26);

          this.tile4.draw(canvas);
      }
      if(Tiles[i].Render == 1){
          this.tile1.setBounds(Tiles[i].mySpritePos.x, Tiles[i].mySpritePos.y,
                  Tiles[i].mySpritePos.x + 26, Tiles[i].mySpritePos.y + 26);

          this.tile1.draw(canvas);

      }
      }}
     }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly how to crop between given bounds, anyway I guess clipping done with `clipDrawableObject.setLevel(level);` where level has range between `0 to 10000`. `setBounds` method (still guessing) only resizes the image withing the given bounds. If you need more detailed information, take a look at [`ClipDrawable.java`](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.java&q=ClipDrawable&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git&type=cs) 's `draw(Canvas blabla)` method.

Still if i were you, i prefer separate image file for each tile. Because, you load a huge image file on a mobile device and there is image processing for clip operations. Good luck anyway.